# Pic-PC (Crossplatform) USB interfacing without writing custom drivers

Tags: pic, usb, driver

I'm planning to use a PIC for a MIDI pedal that can be configured from a PC (through USB). Is there a way to do crossplatform (at least mac/windows, better if also linux) USB in userland (or another way to avoid the hassle of writing a device driver)? I know there's libUSB but I want to know if there's a better solution.

Microchip own drivers are windows-only, if I'm not wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: If you want a cross-plataform ready library, libUSB is the way to start. Just write your code linked dinamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major thing you want to do is get your device to use drivers that are already there.

The [USB HID specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) allows you to tunnel through drivers that are of a standard type and already available on the system.

To my knowledge Windows/Mac/Linux all have this.

Comment: I thought about this but I don't know USB very well and I have to investigate if I can do what I wanna do. Anyway, thank you ;)

Comment: @3mpty, I am getting read to buy something to play with these things, I will let you know what I find out.

Comment: looking forward to hear some news ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Atmel ATmega8U2 as USB to serial converter, like Arduino UNO.

It doesn't require to install any drivers on Mac and Linux and on Windows all you need is a simple `.inf` file

Comment: Or just implement the USB-to-serial in the PIC and not add another processor.